# Can't send audio-file with Aiogram3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, telegram-bot, aiogram

I am writing an Aiogram bot, that takes the link to audio('https://xxxxxxx.mp3'), and sends to user this audio in format of audio.

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.filters import Command, CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message, BotCommand
from aiogram.types.input_file import InputFile
from config_weather import TOKEN_BOT


bot = Bot(token=TOKEN_BOT)
dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message(lambda link: '.mp3' in link.text)
async def process_mp3_link(message: Message):
    try:
        mp3_file = BytesIO(requests.get(message.text).content)
        await bot.send_audio(chat_id=message.chat.id, audio=InputFile(mp3_file))
    except Exception as ex:
        await message.answer('Error!')
        print(ex)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dp.run_polling(bot)
```

Whenever i send a valid link, it replies me with error and terminal throws exception
`Can't instantiate abstract class InputFile with abstract method read`

Saving file to my PC isn't option, I want to implement it without it.

I tries to pass just response of link. response.get().content, BytesIO(response.get().content). ALso tries to implement in through URLInputFile, InputMediaAudio. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens of course because according to the documents, `InputFile.read` is an abstract function. Source: [Inputfile.read](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/types/input_file.html#aiogram.types.input_file.BufferedInputFile.read).

What you should be able to do is to skip BytesIO altogether, and even requests. What you can do instead is to use [InputMediaAudio](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/types/input_media_audio.html#aiogram.types.input_media_audio.InputMediaAudio).

You don't specify what error you get, but with `InputMediaAudio`, you can use the url directly by passing it as the media parameter. Did you try that?

```
await bot.send_audio(chat_id=message.chat.id, audio=InputMediaAudio(media=message.text))
```

Also, you should be able to even skip the whole InputMediaAudio, as `bot.send_audio` also accepts urls [see documentation](https://await%20bot.send_audio(chat_id=message.chat.id,%20audio=InputFile(mp3_file)))

```
await bot.send_audio(chat_id=message.chat.id, audio=message.text)
```